# Xamarin Forms how to give write permissions to a file?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to write my current state of a game into a JSON file so that once the user comes back they can either resume or start new. I'm creating a hello world to take user input, store it in JSON and load it back in.

I currently can load JsonObject very quickly using this method

```
        public JObject GetJsonData(string jsonFileName, string dirNameJsonLivesIn)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonFileName))
                throw new ArgumentNullException(jsonFileName);

            var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var defaultPath = $"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}";
            var extendedPath = $"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{dirNameJsonLivesIn}.{jsonFileName}";

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dirNameJsonLivesIn))
                extendedPath = defaultPath;

            Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(extendedPath);
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var jsonString = reader.ReadToEnd();

                return JObject.Parse(jsonString);
            }
        }
```

With this method, I can access objects with `["strings"]` just like python does very easily and painlessly.

Problem accures when I try to write to the file. I get an error `Access denied`... I have given permission on the manifest for `Write_External_Files` or something along the line. Still get the same error. I've also done some research and there has been a few line of code which people recommended to add to the `MainActivity.cs` but that didn't work either.

Using this method to write file

```
        private void StoreData_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var jsonFileName = "Statefile.json";
            var text = entryBox.Text;
            var state = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            var assembly = typeof(MainPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            var defaultPath = $"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{jsonFileName}";

            state.Add("CurrentState", text);
            
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(state, Formatting.Indented);
            File.WriteAllText(defaultPath, json);
        }
```

Could someone explain why this is happening? Why do I have the ability to read the external_resources but not write to them? Oh yeah, I have set my `properties` to `Embedded Resource` and also `Always Copy`.

Update - **Error**

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException
  Message=Access to the path "/HelloWorldXamarin.Statefile.json" is denied.
```

Comment: Resources are embedded in the app bundle, which is not writable at runtime.  To write to a file you have to use an app folder.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows

Comment: Could you kindly provide an example as an answer I would be very grateful? I also added a copy of the error details I get. Thanks in advance

Comment: Okay so I got it working but is there a way to write to a file that is currently created inside my project and have that be part of the embedded file? I have to use the same default path that is produced to access the information. I don't mind doing it that way but will that file information be saved if the app is closed?

Comment: No, as I explained before, embedded resources are part of the bundle and not writable.  If you need to write to a bundled file, copy it to a writable folder when your app starts.

Comment: If the file wont be saved after a restart what could you suggest for storing state for a game? How can I make a written file after a game have been existed to be stored until next time or unit new game button has been tapped?

Comment: Files are saved after restart